# Что такое token?

Tags: терминология, token

Часто в программирование встречаю это название или фразу на подобии "получаю токен"

Что оно обозначает?

Comment: жетон, одноразовый пропуск.

Comment: @dfhsfhgfj В сети token ring? Или где?

Comment: Это признак. Чаще всего в контексте парсинга.

Answer (score 23):

Термин `token` имеет много разных смыслов. Один из смыслов разъяснен в посте @Heidel, но это лишь один из смыслов, причем не самый частый.

В контексте вопроса, скорее всего, речь идет о немного другом смысле.

Под токеном понимается замещение объекта неким обозначением/идентификатором (часто просто целым числом или строкой). Например: идентификатор сессии это классический токен. Токены широко применяются обычно в системах авторизации/идентификации и проч. Технически обычно реализуются в виде записи в БД, где токен является идентификатором записи о данных юзера или предоставленного доступа. Обычно в этом случае токен вычисляется как хэш комбинации данных юзера (логина), времени создания и ключей сервера ну и проч.

Смысл всего этого в том, что вместо того, чтобы передавать юзеру целый сонм разных данных достаточно дать ему в руки токен и сказать: вот тебе токен и с помощью него можно при необходимости сделать все что надо. Это и удобно и меньше рисков засветки данных.

Answer (score 9):

Токен - это нечто, чем должен обладать пользователь, чтобы получить доступ к ресурсу. Например, доступ к серверу можно организовать через файл Token.dat для каждого пользователя. Каждому пользователю нужно выдать его персональный файл Token.dat, в котором содержится полный список необходимых данных для доступа к ресурсу, например адрес и порт сервера, идентификатор пользователя и его ключ.

Answer (score 4):

Лексема (token) - минимальная единица языка, имеющая самостоятельный смысл. Существуют следующие виды лексем

- имена (идентификаторы);
- ключевые слова;
- знаки операций;
- разделители;
- литералы (константы).

Answer (score -1):

В общем смысле, токен - это символическая единица, представляющая какую-либо ценность или имеющая определенные права и привилегии. Вот некоторые из наиболее распространенных значений токена:

1. В защите информации: Токен может быть использован для идентификации и авторизации пользователя или системы. Например, при входе в систему вы можете предоставить учетные данные (такие как имя пользователя и пароль), и в ответ получить уникальный токен, который будет использоваться для идентификации вас при последующих запросах.
2. В блокчейн-технологиях: Токен может представлять цифровую форму активов, таких как криптовалюта или символические акции. Благодаря токенам возможно создание инновационных моделей экономических систем и криптовалютных сетей.
3. В программировании: Токен - это минимальная единица синтаксиса языка программирования. Код программы состоит из токенов, которые представляют ключевые слова, идентификаторы, операторы, скобки и другие элементы.

В зависимости от контекста, токен может иметь различные значения, но обычно он обозначает некоторую форму идентификации, представления или валюты.
Более подробнее о токенах и операциях с ними читайте на сайте [coins-review.com](https://coins-review.com)

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов, созданных GPT и ChatGPT, недопустима?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12247/220553)

Comment: -1 за рекламу сайта